# Java indexing error by increasing the frequency

Tags: java, indexing, stemming

I have a problem to increase frequency that the word occurs in each file, 
I tested into 3 equal files and obtained different results in each.
Example: Each file the word "program" occurs 13 times
[image]

but the output I have is:
[image]

*the word in the search field as this "programa" and not program because of stemming function

```
[program]
----------------
Doc: site1.html Freq: 21
Doc: site2.html Freq: 11
Doc: site3.html Freq: 1
```

none of the outputs are correct.

The output had to be:

```
[program]
----------------
Doc: site1.html Freq: 13
Doc: site2.html Freq: 13
Doc: site3.html Freq: 13
```

Document class:

```
public class Documento {

    private String docid;
    private int frequencia;

    public Documento(String docid, int frequencia) {
        this.docid = docid;
        this.frequencia = frequencia;
    }

    public String getDocid() {
        return docid;
    }

    public int getFrequencia() {
        return frequencia;
    }

    public void setFrequencia(int frequencia) {
        this.frequencia = frequencia;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ((o instanceof Documento) && docid == ((Documento) o).docid && frequencia == ((Documento) o).frequencia) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Function to insert and find document:

```
        public class Dicionario {

    public Map<String, List<Documento>> indice = new HashMap<>();

    public void InsereDicionario(String palavra, String docid) {
        if (!indice.containsKey(palavra)) {
            indice.put(palavra, new ArrayList<Documento>());
            indice.get(palavra).add(new Documento(docid, 1));
        } else {
            boolean inserido = false;
            List<Documento> lista = indice.get(palavra);
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                Documento d = lista.get(i);
                if (d.getDocid().equals(docid)) {
//                    indice.get(palavra).add(new Documento(docid, 1));
                    inserido = true;
                } else {
                    d.setFrequencia(d.getFrequencia() + 1);
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            if (!inserido) {
                indice.get(palavra).add(new Documento(docid, 1));
            }
        }
    }

    public String Busca(String palavra) {
        String saida = "";
        System.out.println("Buscando [" + palavra + "]");
        List<Documento> list = new ArrayList();

        for (String p : indice.keySet()) {
            if (p.equals(palavra)) {
                list.addAll(indice.get(p));
                for (Documento d : indice.get(p)) {
                    System.out.println("Doc: " + d.getDocid() + " Freq: " + d.getFrequencia());
                    saida += "Doc: " + d.getDocid() + " Freq: " + d.getFrequencia() + "".trim() + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        return saida;
    }
```

Function to call Buscar(Search function) in all words.

```
for (String palavra : query.split(" ")) {
    resultado += ("\n[" + palavra + "]\n----------------\n");
    resultado += dic.Busca(palavra.trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
               if (d.getDocid().equals(docid)) {
//                    indice.get(palavra).add(new Documento(docid, 1));
                    inserido = true;
                } else {
                    d.setFrequencia(d.getFrequencia() + 1);
                }
```

If dociid is found in the list -> then **do nothning**.
Otherwise (a current doc retrieved from the list **is not equal** to `docid`) -> then **increment the counter**.
Swap these operations, or use a negation in the condition.

Comment: Output:
[program]
----------------
Doc: site1.html Freq: 10
Doc: site1.html Freq: 9
Doc: site1.html Freq: 8
Doc: site1.html Freq: 7
Doc: site1.html Freq: 6
Doc: site1.html Freq: 5
Doc: site1.html Freq: 4
Doc: site1.html Freq: 3
Doc: site1.html Freq: 2
Doc: site1.html Freq: 1

Comment: I already tried that, but only appears the frequency of 1 document and decrementing. I am unable to understand what is happening = /